# How should I spend gold?

Tags: diablo-ii

Is there any reason to save gold in *Diablo II*?  With the fairly high percentage you appear to lose on death, should one just blow it all gambling as much as possible?  What is there to do with it save resurrecting dead companions and repairing gear (which seems a pittance compared to what you can bank)?

Comment: Make sure you bank it in your inventory in town to avoid losing it upon dying. You can pay merchants directly from the money that's in your chest.

Comment: @oKtosiTe even if I'm carrying no gold I lose some of what's in my chest upon death.

Comment: I stand corrected; just read about it [at The Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/basics/). @Nick

Comment: Side note: I think you only lose gold from your stash in multi-player modes.

Comment: Why was this received a close vote? It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I find that I mostly only use gold for potions and scrolls (town portal). With that said, I found that when I started using some really high tier items (such as Runeworded items) that the repair costs were phenomenal (and actually sometimes difficult to cover).

Aside from that, here are a couple of other things I find my money going to:

1. Recruit resurrection (in Lord of Destruction). I remember it costing something like 20,000 gold to bring my mercenary back to life every time it died in late nightmare/hell mode.
2. Random items from the shops that are useful for a specific point in time. Sometimes I find myself having a lot of trouble in a given area because of something that an item at a shop just happens to cover. For example, I remember the store selling a +28% fire resistance belt when I was constantly getting killed by fire-damage enemies.
3. Gambling. You can get some nice items (like uniques) from gambling if you have the money. And by the money I mean **a lot** of money.

Comment: People actually take gold for items?  I thought the issue was that gold was worthless so they use other things (P-gems, high level runes, etc)

Comment: **Shudder**. I have to admit that playing hell mode gives you unlimited funds. Main thing for me was repairs. Looked at >50,000 gold per repair with high end items.

Comment: Gambling is probably the most used, next to ressurection. It is common to make a barbarian who specializes in gold farming for gambling purposes.

Comment: Some people will buy immense amount of gold for lower tier items, such as low runes or gems, just because repair costs can be immense sometimes.

Comment: You definitely can sell large volumes of gold for various currencies both in-game (with lots of work) and on Diablo 2 trading sites (for less work) - Id call your fourth point not inapplicable, just the least common use.  Points one and three are your best, and two is...unusual.  If it isn't a +3 War Cries one-handed weapon from a shop, it's probably not actually worth buying with gold.

Comment: +1. You can also use the gold to gamble magic amulets/rings with a high iLevel that can then be used for crafting (if your character has a high level itself). Much quicker than getting these from high level bosses.

Answer (score 7):

Gambling is a great way to spend that pile of gold. You can get some really awesome magical weapons. In my experience, Gheed will give you best weapons in gambling.

You can also spend money on mercenaries. Get mercenaries with max attack and health.

And of course you should have enough gold so that when you die, you can afford some good gear until you reach your corpse to get old items back.

Answer (score 6):

As everyone else said, gambling. I would suggest gambling specifically for **circlets/coronas/tiaras**, or perhaps amulets.

These head pieces can offer extremely good stats which can be better than uniques or set gear of the same slots. As such, gambling for these items can be far more rewarding than gambling for other item slots.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should gamble it all away. Keep a few hundred thousand for mercenary resurrections and repairs though.