# Is it worthwhile to collect gold?

Tags: diablo-ii

In *Diablo II*, the gold drops from monsters and objects in the scenario (like vases). Sometimes you use some skill shot or ranged attack and drops small amounts of gold (like  5 piles of 1 gold each, or 1 stack of 5 gold).

Since I've started playing *Diablo*, I've been addicted to collect all gold in the ground, which consume lot's of time. I'm wondering, is it worth spend time to collect all the gold, or ignoring the small amounts and clearing the dungeon asap (farm) will give you more time/gold?

Some math will be appreciated.

Comment: For the Diablo games, Diablo Wiki has a good article that covers gold and the economy (focusing mostly on Diablo 3): http://www.diablowiki.net/Gold

Comment: @Krazer The link didn't help me. =X

Comment: This seems like it would be highly situational.  What level are you, where are you farming, do you have +GF equipment, etc.  Spend 5 minutes just farming monsters, and track how much gold you gather.  Then don't bother getting other gold unless it gives you a better gold per minute than what you were getting from farming alone.

Comment: Still don't like this question... As I am not you, I cannot tell you how much your time is worth in gold, therefore I cannot give you math.  Also, it would depend from person to person, If i pick up gold twice as fast as you, then for the time you spend i would have amounted 2x the worth.

Comment: Selling body armor later in the game is a better way of collecting gold than picking up every single pile you come across.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I spend gold?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41237/how-should-i-spend-gold)

Comment: @Resorath I don't think so. This question is more " maximizing gains for time spent" than "How should I spend it"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math is not necessary - there are three reasons that **gold is not worthwhile** to go out of your way for:

1. Most of your gear comes from boss runs and player trades, not gold.
2. Almost no players with good gear will trade it for your gold.
3. Very rarely can exceptional gear can be bought from shops ([source](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Item_Generation_Tutorial#Item_Generation_at_Shops)).

Given the above points, it's pretty clear gold isn't enough to get great gear.

However, gold is useful for repairing items and reviving henchmen. You will learn how much that costs when you get there, and you'll see that exhaustively exploring dungeons for gold is not necessary to provide you with repair and revive gold.

If you do really want gold, however, there is a guide especially geared towards finding lots of gold quickly ([source](http://www.diablo2.com/forum/gold-find-barb-t1787.html)). The gear required is pretty tough to get (Enigma among other things) so it will be a while before you can get to that stage, but nonetheless it's possible to farm gold in an extremely efficient way, I suggest you read the guide to find out more.

---

Diablo is more of a speed run game more than an explore and collect game. The reason for this is that your gold does very little to advance you further in the game - leveling is the most effective way to advance. There are efficient ways to level and acquire good gear, and exploring everything while picking up every piece of gold is not one of them.

What you should do is focus on leveling quickly, and with that you will have access to higher difficulties and tougher bosses, which is turn gives *much* more gold and gear for the time spent than exploring dungeons bit by bit. For example, Baal runs (the final boss in the Diablo 2 expansion) are very juicy for collecting xp and gold, and in almost every leveling and farming guide you will see that most of your time is spent killing Baal. Pros who get to the top of their ladder kill Baal thousands of times!

There are many guides on leveling fast in Diablo 2, and a side effect of you leveling fast is that with xp comes lots of gold and gear. These guides are focused on maximizing gains for time spent, and effectively executed you can hit level 75 in under a week with decent gear. [Here's a guide I highly recommend](http://www.gamershell.com/faqs/diablo2lordofdestructionv111highlevelingguide/1.06/) to give you a perspective on the game, it's the story of a pro hitting level 99 first with his character. There are others you should take a look at that are specific to your character class.

Sorry for the lack of math, but Diablo is played the way I explained for a reason: acquiring gold in no way can measure up to the value of leveling quickly. Only collect enough gold to purchase potions and scrolls, repair you items, and revive henchmen, and you will usually get enough as a side effect of simply speed running the game.

Comment: Gold *is* useful in Diablo 2 for reviving henchmen. They can get quite expensive.

Comment: You have somehow managed to make Diablo 2 sound horrifically boring.

Comment: @StrixVaria I my experience henchmen rarely help you out. The exception is a cold henchmen with good support gear, they will save your butt if you are squishy. Especially any spellcaster with a henchman carring Insight. I will have to figure out how to talk about them in my answer.

Comment: @Trevel A number crunch on gold requires a pretty boring/serious outlook on the game. If you want to simply enjoy the game then a number crunch on gold shouldn't matter, although my advice still stands - don't go out of your way for gold, go kill things :)

Comment: A mercenary with the Infinity Runeword is amazing for spellcasters. There are also other very practical uses for mercenaries, especially for Summon Necromancers. I would also note that repair costs for runeword items are extremely expensive, so you either need to save up gold or stockpile Ral runes. I myself have made a gold find barbarian in the past, which has paid dividends by providing me with constant repair and gambling gold.

Comment: @Kotsu Good points, but manual goldfind is pretty brutal without proper gear, which requires a fair time investment in the first place. Should I include a blurb about making a gold find character? Advice on gold find bots would not apply since it's against ToS and I cannot promote doing that here.

Comment: I just went and added a blurb. That's a build I wasn't aware of, and although the gear is pretty intense to get if you're not already far into the game, it certainly gets gold with minimal effort.

Comment: Gold is certainly something worthwhile to have a lot of, but you definitely are correct in saying that devoting time to pick up every bit of gold you see isn't worth it, especially in Normal and Nightmare mode.

Comment: I was really looking forward to maximizing gains for time spent, Great answer, really appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

Gold can be extremely useful; however, it's not worth going out of your way to pick it up unless your character is wearing a large amount of gold find, since the time/reward ratio is very low for picking up piles of 4-5 gold. Piles of 4000-5000 gold, on the other hand, are worth the trip.

Most players need gold for two reasons: reviving mercenaries (especially sorceresses with Insight or Infinity mercenaries, who lose effectiveness when their mercenary dies), and repairing weapons and armor (mostly for melee characters).

There is, however, a valuable use for gold if you can get it in large quantities: gambling for rare circlets and amulets.

Necromancers will often find themselves automatically building up gold in quantity, because they don't have a gold sink, but the most effective purpose-built gold farmers are said to be barbarians encrusted with Lem runes, running the council and horking dead bodies with find item. Council runs are also known to be one of the best sources of runes, producing many more high runes per unit time than Countess runs.

Several of the best items in the game can be gotten by gold farming and gambling, in particular +2 class skills circlets with 20% faster cast rate (particularly valuable with faster hit recovery, good resists, and/or dual sockets). Because circlets, coronets, tiaras and diadems give a boost to the item's magic level, gambling for them has a decent chance of creating good items even for mid-level characters.

Some of the magical (blue) circlets can also be quite valuable; for example, the highest magic find helm is an extremely rare magical tiara/diadem with three sockets (from a specific prefix) and 35% magic find (the maximum possible for the best suffix), fitted with three ist runes, and the best chance of finding one is from gambling.

High level characters (level 86 to have a chance, level 95 for the maximum chance) can also gamble for +2 class skills rare amulets with 10% faster cast rate and other bonuses, which can have very high trade value, partly because reaching a good level to gamble for them is extremely tedious. (Crafted caster amulets with 15-20% fcr are more valuable, but good rares with more affixes than crafted amulets are often better for characters that reach their target fcr with only 10% from the amulet.)